# Organising asynchronous tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have three tasks A, B, C.

B must run before C, but A can run in parallel to both of them.  This is logic that has recently changed, and the logic we currently have works fine, I just wondered if there is a better solution to what we currently have:

```
public void RunTasks(...) {
    Action<IRunnableTask> runner = task => 
    {
        if (task.ShouldRun(request))
        {
            task.Run(request, response);
        }
    };

    // run parallel tasks
    Parallel.ForEach(parallelTasks, runner);

    // run serial tasks
    Array.ForEach(serialTasks, runner);
}
```

Here, A and B would be parallel tasks, C is in the list of serial tasks.  The problem is here that the code will wait for A to finish before C can start, which is unnecessary.

So, is there a nice clean solution, or do I need to start putting in callbacks and whatnot?

Comment: It's not stated in the question, but if you want to do something when both A and C are done, you can Task.WhenAll them and then ContinueWith on that.

Comment: Also, depending on the code for B and C, they don't have to be separate tasks, but you could just have a single task that runs the B code and then runs the C code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of Tasks from the TPL.

You could run Tasks B and A at the same time, then have task C run as a continuation of Task B

e.g.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>TaskA());
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>TaskB()).ContinueWith(t=>TaskC(t));
```

In the continuation of TaskB, you can pass in the Task to get any result of TaskB passed into the TaskC method.

Comment: Depending on the actual logic, could also have the second line be Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { TaskB(); TaskC(); }); :)

Comment: James, you could, but TaskC would not know anything about the result of TaskB in that case, and also, makes things like error handling very messy. I certainly would not recommend it. Tasks should be discrete.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a task to the list of parallel tasks, whose responsibility it is to execute the serial tasks one after another?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
Action taskACallback = () => { };
Action taskBCallback = () => { };
Action taskCCallback = () => { };

Task taskA = new Task(taskACallback);
Task taskC = new Task(taskCCallback);
Task taskB = new Task(taskBCallback).ContinueWith(t => taskC.Start());
taskA.Start();
taskB.Start();
```

Comment: AFAIK, when using ContinueWith, you pass a Func or Action, not a task, so you'd instead do something like "Task taskB = new Task(taskBCallback);" and "Task taskC = taskB.ContinueWith(t => taskCCallback());" - the existing code would actually assign ContinueWith task to the taskB variable and throw at runtime trying to Start() it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly modified version of sll's answer since I'm not sure what the etiquette around editing code to this extent is.

```
Action taskACallback = () => Console.WriteLine ("Task A");
Action taskBCallback = () => Console.WriteLine ("Task B");
Action<Task> taskCCallback = task => Console.WriteLine ("Task C, continued off of task with status {0}", task.Status);

Task taskA = new Task(taskACallback);
Task taskB = new Task(taskBCallback);
Task taskC = taskB.ContinueWith(taskCCallback);
taskA.Start();
taskB.Start();
```

This gives console output of:

```
Task A
Task B
Task C, continued off of task with status RanToCompletion
```